# Are system calls scheduled?

Tags: windows, system-calls

What system process is responsible for executing system call, when user process calls ‘system call’ and the CPU switches to supervisor mode?

Are system calls scheduled by thread scheduler (can CPU switch to executing another system call after getting interrupt)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What system process is responsible for executing system call?
The system call wrapper(the function you call to perform the system call, yeah it's just a wrapper, not the actually System call) will take the parameters, pass them to the approperiate registers(or on stack, depends on implementation), next it will put the system call number you're requesting in the `eax` (assuming x86) and finally will call `INT 0x80` assembly instruction which is basically telling the OS that it received an interrupt and this interrupt is a system call that needs to be served, which system call to serve is available in the `eax` and the parameters are in the registers.

(modern implementations stopped using `INT` because it's expensive in performance and now use `SYSENTER` and `SYSEXIT`; the above is still almost the same though)

From the perspective of the scheduler, it makes no difference if you perform a system call or not; the thing is, once you ask the OS for a service(via the x86 instruction `INT` or `SYSENTER` and `SYSEXIT` ) the CPU mode flag will change to a privileged set, then the kernel will perform the task you asked for on behalf of your process and once done, it sets the flag back and returns the execution to the next instruction.

So, from a scheduler point of view, the OS will see no difference when you execute a system call or anything else.

Few notes:
-What I mentioned above is a general description, I am not sure if Windows applies this but if it doesn't, it should be doing something of similar fashion.
-Many System Calls perform blocking tasks(like I/O handling); to make better CPU utilization if your process asks for a blocking system call, the scheduler will let your process wait in the wait-queue till what it requested is ready, meanwhile other processes run on the CPU BUT do not confuse this with anything, the OS did not 'schedule system calls'.

The scheduler's task is to organize tasks, and from its perspective the system call is just a routine that the process is executing.

A final note, some system calls are atomic which means they should be performed without any interruption to their execution, these system calls if interrupted, will be be asked to restart execution once the interrupt's cause is over; still this is far from the scheduling concept.

Answer (score 0):

First question: it depends. Some system calls go to services which are already running (say a network call) as a process. Some system calls result in a new process getting created and then getting scheduled for execution.

Last question: yes windows is a multiprocessing system. The process scheduler handles when a thread runs, for how long, and hardware interrupts can end up causing the running process to release the CPU or a idle process that the hardware is now ready for to get the CPU.

In windows (at least > Win 7 but I think in the past it was true too) a lot of the system services run in processes called svchost. A good application for seeing what is running were is Process Explorer from sys internals. It is like task manager on steroids and will show you all the threads that a given process owns. For finer grained "I called this dos command what happened" details you'd probably want to use a debugging tool where you can step through your call. Generally though you don't have to concern yourself with these things, you make a system call the system knows you aren't ready to continue processing until whatever process is handling that request has returned. Your request might get the CPU right after your process releases it, it might get the CPU 2 days from now but as far as the OS is concerned (or your program should be concerned) it doesn't matter, execution stops and waits for a result unless you are running multithreaded and then it gets really complicated.

Comment: „Some system calls go to services which are already running…”
But this it done by IPC inside system call routine which is running on the same process that starts system call, but in kernel mode, yes?